# Get the range of the last X rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, average

Say I have a spreadsheet with 18 rows, and I can hard code the range of the last 7 values in column D and average their values like so:

```
=AVERAGE(D12:D18)
```

How then could I do the same without hard coding them, so it'll work as I add more rows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to calculate the average or sum, there's no need for a script. You can accomplish this with an array filter as well. The following formula calculates the average over the last 7 rows in the A column:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(A:A;ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A:A)>COUNT(A:A)-7+1)))
```

This assumes that the data starts at row 1. Otherwise you have to change the latter constant in the formula to the row number where the data starts.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `OFFSET()` as this [Webapps.SO answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/40345/20835) does for aggregating over the last X cells of a row.

For the opposite---aggregating the last X cells of a column---the OFFSET params just need moving around. Here's a command should should work for your example (this assumes your data starts at D2 and goes to D18):

```
=iferror(average(offset($D$2, max(0, count($D$2:$D18)-7), 0, 7, 1)), 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you can use your own code. Messy, but it works:

```
function lastValues(column, num) {
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getMaxRows();
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(column + "1:" + column + lastRow).getValues();

  for (; values[lastRow - 1] == "" && lastRow > 0; lastRow--) {};

  arr = [];

  for(i=0; i < num+1; i++){
    arr.push(values[lastRow - i]);
  };

  return arr;
};
```

Comment: It complains - Argument must be range!